# What does upstart means? How to solve this issue?

Tags: upstart, lamp

[image]

I've tried this

```
sudo apt-get install upstart
```

But I get this as feedback.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
upstart is already the newest version
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? And please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals). Paste the text directly to your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon).

Comment: It's ubuntu 16.04 LTS.